# fadeto jquery function on all page but few (tagged) elements

Tags: jquery, tags, fadeto

I am using this simple script on a webpage:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("notowned").fadeTo(2000,0.2,function(){
   });
});
</script>
```

so all elements (images) under the "notowned" tag are grayed out.
However, it is quite counter-intuitive to programs pages like that, so i wanted to do the reverse: fade out all elements and then add "owned" tags to those who should not be grayed out.
I tried various ways, like making two tags, but it did not work.
Anyone can help me with that?
Thanks!

EDIT:
here is the jfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/4tkH6/
note that i have over 118 elements, so I want them to be grayed out by default and then "ungrey" some of them with a tag or something.
AFAIK fadetoggle removes them completely so it is not good for me.

Comment: give in your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Playground](http://jsbin.com/layak/1/edit)**

`<notowned>` tag is not a standard tag neither in HTML5, so **don't use it**.

Use standard elements like `<div>` and if you need 'em special assign a custom `data-*` attribute for that purpose:

```
<div data-owned="0">image 1</div>
<div data-owned="1">image 2</div>
<div data-owned="0">image 3</div>
<div data-owned="0">image 4</div>
<div data-owned="0">image 5</div>
```

CSS example:

```
[data-owned='0']{ opacity: 0.3; }
[data-owned='1']{ opacity: 1  ; }
```

JS/jQ toggle data state example:

```
$('[data-owned]').click(function(){
  this.dataset.owned ^= 1; // Toggle 0/1
});
```